# No importa la libreria de Chatterbot a mi codigo de Python

Tags: python, vscode, python-import

muy buenas a todos! Aqui les va mi problema que tuve al programar mi asistente virtual
No importa la libreria de chatterbot, esta instalada correctamente sin embargo en el VS code, me aparece este error al momento de ver los fallos en el codigo:Import "ChatterBot" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
Me pueden ayudar en como resolverlo o importarlo correctamente?
O como pueda solucionar el chatterbot, se me olvido mencionar que tengo instalada la version 1.0.4

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3, pywhatkit, wikipedia
import database
from ChatterBot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

name = "Lucia"
listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)

def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def listen():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as sorce:
            print("Escuchando Xque")
            pc = listener.listen(sorce)
           rec = listener.recognize_google(pc, language="es")
            rec.lower()
            if name in rec:
                rec = rec.replace(name, '')

    except:
        print("Algo salio terreiblemente mal imbecil")
    return rec


#comentaeio randonm la neta

def run_Lucia():
    while True:
     rec = listen()
     if 'Reproduce' in rec:
        music = rec.replace('Reproduce', '')
        print("Reproduciendo" + music)
        talk("Reproduciendo" + music)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(music)
     if 'busca' in rec:
       search = rec.replace('busca', '')
       wikipedia.set_lang("es")
       wiki = wikipedia.summary(search, 1)
       print(search +": " + wiki)
       talk(wiki)
     if 'Hora de la comedia' in rec:
         chat = ChatBot("lucia", database_uri=None)
         trainer = ListTrainer(chat)
         trainer.train(database.get_comedy())
         talk("Vamos a reirnos un rato:) *Carita Feliz*")
         while True:
            try:
                rec = listen()
            except UnboundLocalError:
                talk("No te entendi, intenta de nuevo")
                continue
            print("Tu: ", rec)
            answer = chat.get_response(rec)
            print("Lucia: ", answer)
            talk(answer)
            if 'adios' in rec:
                break



if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_Lucia()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En la línea donde importas "ChatterBot", cambia "ChatterBot" por "chatterbot". El nombre de la librería es "chatterbot", no "ChatterBot", por lo que deberías importarla de la siguiente manera:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
```

En la línea donde importas "ListTrainer", cambia "ListTrainer" por "ChatterBotCorpusTrainer". El nombre correcto de la clase es "ChatterBotCorpusTrainer", no "ListTrainer", por lo que deberías importarla de la siguiente manera:

```
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
```

Si haces estos cambios, debería funcionar correctamente y no deberías tener el error que mencionas. Si aún tienes problemas, no dudes en preguntar.